# How can I get jcifs to play nicely with apache axis

Tags: java, apache-axis, ntlm

I need to connect Apache Axis 1.4 to a Webservice that uses NTLM authentication to restrict access to its operations.
I'm expecting to use Samba Jcifs to handle the NTLM handshake.

I found

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/ntlm.html

which gives me fantastic directions for how to wire up HttpClient 4.0 with jcifs.

Trouble is, Axis wants to use Http Client 3.0 and the two apis look very different.

There are 2 possibilities that I can see

1. Write an object for Axis that lets it plug into HttpClient 4.
2. Figure out how to wire HttpClient 3.0 up with Samba Jcifs.

Number 1. looks non-trivial, but possible
Number 2. I cannot find any encouraging messages on the web describing how to do this.

My question is: has anyone successfully connected samba jcifs with HttpClient 3.0 ?
Has anyone already created an Axis HttpSender object that works with HttpClient 4 ?

Is there some better alternative that I have not considered?

Comment: huh?
Jcifs is for the CIFS filesystem, right? 
Do you just want the authentication part? 

But Apache Commons' HttpClient includes NTLM authentication.  ??? 

What are "SQL endpoints"?

What, in the end, are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to access a webservice that uses NTLM handshakes to control access to its operaions.
I think HttpClient does NOT provide NTLM support due to intellectual property problems.
I believe I can use Samba Jcifs to create the NTLM Type 1 Message and the Type3 Message. The fact that its an SQL database hiding behind the Webservice is an irrelevant detail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally have a solution to this.

#### The problem

Apache Axis uses Apache `HTTPClient` which provides its own NTLM implementation.
However this implementation is incomplete; it only supports the primitive LM authentication.
The system I need to connect to insists upon the more recent NTLM authentication.

Therefore my Webservice was failing to authenticate when using the Apache HTTP Client with NTLM.

This actually then enters an infinite loop as the `HTTPClient` will never stop trying and failing to authenticate.

#### The solution

jcifs fully supports all 3 versions of the NTLM handshake.
I have copy-and-pasted `org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.NTLM` into my own class (it is declared as 'final' in order to defeat inheritance)

I have then overwritten the method

```
public String getType3Message(
        String user, String password, String host, String domain,
        byte[] nonce) throws AuthenticationException
```

to construct an instance of `jcifs.ntlmssp.Type3Message`
and use this object to return a `Type3Message` that has the NTML authentication correctly generated.

I then needed to create my own instance of `org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthScheme`
to make use of this new NTLM implementation. call 
`org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthPolicy.registerAuthScheme(AuthPolicy.NTLM, MyNewAuthScheme.class)`

start up my WS endpoint stub.

And it works !!!

Comment: Good solution but it has one drawback. AuthPolicy.registerAuthScheme() would register MyNewAuthScheme with NTLM and any future request for NTLM would use this scheme instead of the original NTLMScheme from apache commons httpclient. This could be an issue if you intend to narrow down your code fix to a specific feature in your software.

Comment: Any change you could paste your entire code for this somewhere? Cause I am strugling with the exact same problem right now.

Answer (score 2):

In response to Sergey's comment...

I have two clases in my solution. An Authorisation Scheme like this

```
import java.io.IOException;

import jcifs.ntlmssp.Type1Message;
import jcifs.ntlmssp.Type2Message;
import jcifs.ntlmssp.Type3Message;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.Credentials;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.NTCredentials;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthChallengeParser;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthScheme;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthenticationException;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.InvalidCredentialsException;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.MalformedChallengeException;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.NTLMScheme;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.util.EncodingUtil;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

/**
 * AuthScheme that delegates the work of reading and writing NTLM messages to
 * the JCIFS implementation
 * 
 * directly inspired by org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.NTLMScheme
 * 
 *
 * This software is based upon voluntary contributions made by many
 * individuals on behalf of the Apache Software Foundation.  For more
 * information on the Apache Software Foundation, please see
 * .
 *
 */
public class JcifsNtlmScheme implements AuthScheme
{
    /** Log object for this class. */
    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(NTLMScheme.class);

    /** NTLM challenge string. */
    private String ntlmchallenge = null;

    private static final int UNINITIATED = 0;
    private static final int INITIATED = 1;
    private static final int TYPE1_MSG_GENERATED = 2;
    private static final int TYPE2_MSG_RECEIVED = 3;
    private static final int TYPE3_MSG_GENERATED = 4;
    private static final int FAILED = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    /** Authentication process state */
    private int state;

    /**
     * Default constructor for the NTLM authentication scheme.
     * 
     * @since 3.0
     */
    public JcifsNtlmScheme()
    {
        super();
        this.state = UNINITIATED;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for the NTLM authentication scheme.
     * 
     * @param challenge
     *            The authentication challenge
     * 
     * @throws MalformedChallengeException
     *             is thrown if the authentication challenge is malformed
     */
    public JcifsNtlmScheme(final String challenge)
            throws MalformedChallengeException
    {
        super();
        processChallenge(challenge);
    }

    /**
     * Processes the NTLM challenge.
     * 
     * @param challenge
     *            the challenge string
     * 
     * @throws MalformedChallengeException
     *             is thrown if the authentication challenge is malformed
     * 
     * @since 3.0
     */
    public void processChallenge(final String challenge)
            throws MalformedChallengeException
    {
        String s = AuthChallengeParser.extractScheme(challenge);
        if (!s.equalsIgnoreCase(getSchemeName()))
        {
            throw new MalformedChallengeException("Invalid NTLM challenge: "
                    + challenge);
        }
        int i = challenge.indexOf(' ');
        if (i != -1)
        {
            s = challenge.substring(i, challenge.length());
            this.ntlmchallenge = s.trim();
            this.state = TYPE2_MSG_RECEIVED;
        }
        else
        {
            this.ntlmchallenge = "";
            if (this.state == UNINITIATED)
            {
                this.state = INITIATED;
            }
            else
            {
                this.state = FAILED;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Tests if the NTLM authentication process has been completed.
     * 
     * @return true if Basic authorization has been processed,
     *         false otherwise.
     * 
     * @since 3.0
     */
    public boolean isComplete()
    {
        return this.state == TYPE3_MSG_GENERATED || this.state == FAILED;
    }

    /**
     * Returns textual designation of the NTLM authentication scheme.
     * 
     * @return ntlm
     */
    public String getSchemeName()
    {
        return "ntlm";
    }

    /**
     * The concept of an authentication realm is not supported by the NTLM
     * authentication scheme. Always returns null.
     * 
     * @return null
     */
    public String getRealm()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Unsupported.
     */
    public String getID()
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the authentication parameter with the given name, if available.
     * 
     * 
     * There are no valid parameters for NTLM authentication so this method
     * always returns null.
     * 
     * 
     * @param name
     *            The name of the parameter to be returned
     * 
     * @return the parameter with the given name
     */
    public String getParameter(String name)
    {
        if (name == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter name may not be null");
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true. NTLM authentication scheme is connection based.
     * 
     * @return true.
     * 
     * @since 3.0
     */
    public boolean isConnectionBased()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Unsupported.
     */
    public static String authenticate(
            final NTCredentials credentials, final String challenge)
            throws AuthenticationException
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    /**
     * Unsupported.
     */
    public static String authenticate(
            final NTCredentials credentials, final String challenge,
            String charset) throws AuthenticationException
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    /**
     * Unsupported.
     */
    public String authenticate(
            Credentials credentials, String method, String uri)
            throws AuthenticationException
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();

    }

    /**
     * Produces NTLM authorization string for the given set of
     * {@link Credentials}.
     * 
     * @param credentials
     *            The set of credentials to be used for athentication
     * @param method
     *            The method being authenticated
     * 
     * @throws InvalidCredentialsException
     *             if authentication credentials are not valid or not applicable
     *             for this authentication scheme
     * @throws AuthenticationException
     *             if authorization string cannot be generated due to an
     *             authentication failure
     * 
     * @return an NTLM authorization string
     * 
     * @since 3.0
     */
    public String authenticate(Credentials credentials, HttpMethod method)
            throws AuthenticationException
    {
        LOG.trace("enter NTLMScheme.authenticate(Credentials, HttpMethod)");

        if (this.state == UNINITIATED)
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "NTLM authentication process has not been initiated");
        }

        NTCredentials ntcredentials = null;
        try
        {
            ntcredentials = (NTCredentials) credentials;
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e)
        {
            throw new InvalidCredentialsException(
                    "Credentials cannot be used for NTLM authentication: "
                            + credentials.getClass().getName());
        }
        byte[] msgBytes = null;
        String response = null;
        if (this.state == INITIATED)
        {
            Type1Message msg = new Type1Message();
            // @see http://davenport.sourceforge.net/ntlm.html#theType1Message
            // dont' support Unicode
            // negotiate OEM
            // request authentication realm in Type2 response
            // not signed
            // not encrypted
            // not authenticated
            // no lan manager key
            // negotiate NTLM
            msg.setFlags(0x5206);
            msg.setSuppliedWorkstation(ntcredentials.getHost());
            msg.setSuppliedDomain(ntcredentials.getDomain());
            msgBytes = msg.toByteArray();
            this.state = TYPE1_MSG_GENERATED;
        }
        else if (this.state == TYPE2_MSG_RECEIVED)
        {
            byte[] msg2Bytes =
                    Base64.decodeBase64(EncodingUtil.getBytes(
                            this.ntlmchallenge,
                            method.getParams().getCredentialCharset()));
            try
            {
                Type2Message msg2 = new Type2Message(msg2Bytes);
                Type3Message msg3 =
                        new Type3Message(msg2, ntcredentials.getPassword(),
                                ntcredentials.getDomain(), ntcredentials
                                        .getUserName(), ntcredentials.getHost());
                msgBytes = msg3.toByteArray();
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                throw new AuthenticationException(
                        "unable to parse Type2Message", ex);
            }
            this.state = TYPE3_MSG_GENERATED;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("failed to authenticate");
        }
        response = EncodingUtil.getAsciiString(Base64.encodeBase64(msgBytes));
        return "NTLM " + response;
    }
}
```

And a class to register the authorisation scheme, like this

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.Credentials;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.NTCredentials;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthPolicy;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthScheme;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.CredentialsNotAvailableException;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.DefaultHttpParams;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.DefaultHttpParamsFactory;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpParams;

/**
 * registers NTLM authentication for apache axis
 * 
 */
public class NtlmJcifsCredentials
{
    public static void register(String password)
    {
        final String username = System.getProperty("user.name");
        final String computername = System.getenv("COMPUTERNAME");
        final String userDomain = System.getenv("USERDOMAIN");
        register(username, password, computername, userDomain);
    }
    public static void register(String username, String password, String userDomain)
    {
        final String computername = System.getenv("COMPUTERNAME");
        register(username, password, computername, userDomain);
    }

    public static void register(
            String username, String password, String computername, String domain)
    {
        final NTCredentials ntCred =
                new NTCredentials(username, password, computername, domain);

        final CredentialsProvider ntlmCredProvider = new CredentialsProvider()
        {
            public Credentials getCredentials(
                    AuthScheme scheme, String host, int port, boolean proxy)
                    throws CredentialsNotAvailableException
            {
                return ntCred;
            }
        };
        final DefaultHttpParamsFactory paramFact =
                new DefaultHttpParamsFactory()
                {
                    @Override
                    protected HttpParams createParams()
                    {
                        HttpParams htp = super.createParams();
                        htp.setParameter(
                                CredentialsProvider.PROVIDER,
                                ntlmCredProvider);
                        return htp;
                    }
                };
        DefaultHttpParams.setHttpParamsFactory(paramFact);

        // we want all our jcifs encoding to be ascii
        jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.encoding", "ASCII");

        // our jcifs implemented NTLM is required for MDW's authentication
        AuthPolicy.registerAuthScheme(AuthPolicy.NTLM, JcifsNtlmScheme.class);
    }
}
```

At runtime I call

```
 NtlmJcifsCredentials.register(username, password, domain)
```

I construct my endpoint stub, and it just works.
As a beneficial side-effect this will simply chuck an exception if if fails to authenticate - the Default Apache Commons class will keep trying to connect infinitely - which in the case of NTLM can easily lead to your account being locked out from windows.

Answer (score 2):

Thank yo very much Ben, good work.
For my solution I need 2 improvements, based on your classes.

1)  **class JcifsNtlmScheme**

The interface has changed in jcifs (I use version 1.3.14).
The NTLM flag is required, I'm not really sure but 0x82 works for me.

```
int flags = Type3Message.NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_OEM | Type3Message.NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_LM_KEY;

Type3Message msg3 =
        new Type3Message(msg2, ntcredentials.getPassword(),
        ntcredentials.getDomain(), ntcredentials.getUserName(), ntcredentials.getHost(), flags);
```

2) **class NtlmJcifsCredentials**

```
 DefaultHttpParams.setHttpParamsFactory(paramFact);
```

This works fine for the first connection. It seems to be a global setting. It's probably not really thread-safe.
I need the credentials on connections base. So I dropped this class and inserted the built-in Authenticator directly after creation of the webservice stub:

```
jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.encoding", "ASCII");
AuthPolicy.registerAuthScheme(AuthPolicy.NTLM, JcifsNtlmScheme.class);

Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator();
List<String> authScheme = new ArrayList<String>();
authScheme.add(Authenticator.NTLM);
authScheme.add(Authenticator.BASIC);
authenticator.setAuthSchemes(authScheme);
authenticator.setUsername(myusername);
authenticator.setPassword(mypassword);
authenticator.setHost(servername);
authenticator.setDomain(domain);        
exService._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, authenticator);       
exService._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.CHUNKED, Boolean.FALSE);
exService._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.REUSE_HTTP_CLIENT, Boolean.TRUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got it working, but I did NOT yet implement proxy server support in the HTTP.
http://www.magsoft.nl/share/Axis2%20patch.zip
All the jars I use are in the project lib directory.
There are some class path requirements. First the Axis2 HTTPClient4 patch.jar has to be above the axis jars. Furthermore, commons-httpclient-3.1.jar needs to be still in the classpath, but after the httpclient-4 jars.

Here is how I implemented the client:

```
Scheme http = new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80);
SchemeRegistry sr = new SchemeRegistry();
sr.register(http);
HttpParams httpParms = new BasicHttpParams();
ClientConnectionManager connManager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(httpParms, sr);
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(connManager, httpParms);
httpclient.getAuthSchemes().register(HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator.NTLM, new NTLMSchemeFactory());
httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(host, -1), new NTCredentials(user, pass, host, domain));

sps = new SharepointServiceStub(addr.toString());

List authScheme = new ArrayList();
authScheme.add(HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator.NTLM);
HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator auth = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();
auth.setHost(host);
auth.setDomain(domain);
auth.setUsername(user);
auth.setPassword(pass);
auth.setAuthSchemes(authScheme);
Options options = sps._getServiceClient().getOptions();
options.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.REUSE_HTTP_CLIENT, true);
options.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.CACHED_HTTP_CLIENT, httpclient);
options.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, auth);
options.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.CHUNKED, Boolean.TRUE);
options.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 900000); // 15 minutes
options.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.SO_TIMEOUT, 180000); // 3 minutes
```

But for this to work you will need the following tree classes:
NTLMSchemeFactory.java

```
package ...;

import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScheme;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthSchemeFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.NTLMScheme;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

public class NTLMSchemeFactory implements AuthSchemeFactory
{

    public NTLMSchemeFactory()
    {
    }

    public AuthScheme newInstance(final HttpParams params)
    {
        return new NTLMScheme(new JCIFSEngine());
    }

}
```

JCIFSScheme.java

```
package ...;

import org.apache.http.impl.auth.NTLMScheme;



public class JCIFSScheme extends NTLMScheme
{
    public JCIFSScheme()
    {
        super(new JCIFSEngine());
    }
}
```

JCIFSEngine.java

```
package ...;

import java.io.IOException;

import jcifs.ntlmssp.Type1Message;
import jcifs.ntlmssp.Type2Message;
import jcifs.ntlmssp.Type3Message;
import jcifs.util.Base64;

import org.apache.http.impl.auth.NTLMEngine;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.NTLMEngineException;

public class JCIFSEngine implements NTLMEngine
{
    public String generateType1Msg(String domain, String workstation) throws NTLMEngineException
    {

        Type1Message t1m = new Type1Message(Type1Message.getDefaultFlags(), domain, workstation);
        return Base64.encode(t1m.toByteArray());
    }


    public String generateType3Msg(String username, String password, String domain, String workstation, String challenge)
            throws NTLMEngineException
    {
        Type2Message t2m;
        try
        {
            t2m = new Type2Message(Base64.decode(challenge));
        } catch (IOException ex)
        {
            throw new NTLMEngineException("Invalid Type2 message", ex);
        }
        Type3Message t3m = new Type3Message(t2m, password, domain, username, workstation, 0);
        return Base64.encode(t3m.toByteArray());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This [Axis2Patch.zip](http://www.magsoft.nl/share/Axis2%20patch.zip) has been a real lifesaver. 
This is what I did:

Compiled Axis2Patch with httpclient4.1 beta1 which has NTLMv2 build in. 
Imported that into my project and imported httpclient4.1beta1 also.

I changed my imports like this:

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthenticationException;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.NTLMScheme;
//import org.apache.commons.httpclient.NTCredentials;
//import org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthPolicy;

import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.NTCredentials;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.client.params.AuthPolicy;
```

and without too much code change it works perfectly. 
Thanks!