# Axis2 NTLM Authentication for Proxy-Server

Tags: java, authentication, proxy, apache-axis, ntlm

What is the correct way to authenticate an Axis2 (Version 1.4) Client at a http proxy server that requires NTLM authentication?

I'm using the following code to provide the proxy credentials, but the authentication still fails (see details at the end):

```
Options options = serviceStub._getServiceClient().getOptions();
options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.CHUNKED, false);
options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HTTPConstants.HEADER_PROTOCOL_10);

ProxyProperties proxyProperties = new ProxyProperties();
proxyProperties.setProxyName("123.123.123.123");
proxyProperties.setProxyPort(8080);
proxyProperties.setUserName("myUser@www.example.org");
proxyProperties.setPassWord("1234");
proxyProperties.setDomain("");
options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.PROXY, proxyProperties);
```

With exactly the same credentials, a webbrowser, such as Firefox is able to get trough the proxy, so I assume, the proxy server is correctly set up. With the Axis2 client however, the authentication failes (HTTP status code is "407 Proxy Authentication Required").

Further details:
I compared the network traffic from firefox and my client using a network sniffer. The main difference seems to be, that the axis2 client is sending an empty response for the ntlm challenge.

Has anyone successfully authenticated at a http proxy server using NTLM? Can you give me a code example?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916820/how-can-i-get-jcifs-to-play-nicely-with-apache-axis/1531406#1531406

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to resolve this problem (with Axis 2). Don't want to blame this on Axis2 tough. Maybe I did something wrong but couldn't figure it out, even after many hours of trying, debugging and reading the docs.

But when I was running out of options I had to look out for other options. This other option came in the form of alternative SOAP-Frameworks. There exist quite a few SOAP frameworks for java. I know about Axis2, CXF and JAX-WS.

Instead of Axis2 I use now JAX-WS. Replacing the frameworks was a straight forward process. A nice side effect of the replacement was, that I got rid of the huge dependency tree, Axis2 comes with. JAX-WS is part of J6EE so there wasn't any need to import other dependencies.

At this time I did the replacement only on the client side. The server still uses Axis2. This combination works great so far, but I still plan to eventually replace Axis2 on the server side too.

All in all: If you do not use a special feature of Axis2, I think, JAX-WS is the better option.