# Java HTTP NTLM Implementation Differences

Tags: java, windows, ntlm, apache-commons-httpclient

This [link](http://oaklandsoftware.com/papers/ntlm.html) details on the various http client java implementations. I am looking for any links which could provide information about their NTLM protocol implementation differences.

On one of the windows machine, I found that the commons-http client 3.1 implementation fails with an authorization error (http status code 401) but the java 1.5 implementation succeeds. Since the java 1.5 implementation of the NTLM authentication protocol is not open source, I cannot compare the two implementations to understand what could be going wrong.

**Update 1**

I am aware of the fact that commons http client does not support NTLM v2. This [link](http://oaklandsoftware.com/product_http/compare.html) provides a comparison between various java http client implementations and mentions that apache http client provides a **partial** implementation of NTLM protocol. It does not detail more about it.

On troubleshooting the issue further I also found that the NTLM implementation provided by [this link](http://www.luigidragone.com/?page_id=19) in combination with [HTTPClient](http://www.innovation.ch/) works on the windows machine (the commons http client implementation does not work as I mention above).

**Update 2**

By sniffing packets (using wireshack) I realized that the commons http client 3.1 ntlm protocol implementation does not generate the NTLM Response in the Type 3 message. This is generated by the JDK implementation. Do you know of any server/client setting which indicates that the authentication would fail if the NTLM response data is empty? (since the authentication failure we are facing is reproducible only on one machine. The authentication succeeds else where.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the root cause of this issue. The configuration setting which lead to the authentication error was controlled by a security policy called NoLMHashPolicy. Enabling this policy means the windows server would no more store the LM Hash value for any password and it would use the NT Response hash to do the authentication. Since the NTLM protocol implementation from commons http client 3.1 library does not at all calculate the NT response one could face this error when this setting is enabled. More details about this setting can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299656).

As a solution one could just add an implementation of the AuthScheme interface and extract out the code from higher versions of the commons http client library (for e.g. 4.1.2) which computes the NT Response in the Type 3 message. Do not forget to update the length and the offset values for the NT Response fields. 
Once the implementation of AuthScheme interface is ready it can be injected using the AuthPolicy.registeryScheme() method.

Answer (score 1):

Commons httpclient 3.1 does not implement NTLMv2, it only implements the older NTLM (aka NTLMv1) specification.

Comment: Right. But that doesn't seem to be the issue for the windows machine I  mention about since accessing the resource using a browser (internet explorer) works. The HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\LmCompatibilityLevel on that machine is 2 which indicates that the browser uses NTLM v1.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, but I don't think that LmCompatibilityLevel is a guarantee here.  Especially since this only has an impact on NTLM settings and not SPNEGO.  Have you used Wireshark to determine what IE is sending?  I suspect it's not NTLMv1.  See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.08.securitywatch.aspx for a detailed discussion about LmCompatibilityLevel and its limitations (which, unfortunately, does not discuss Kerberos/SPNEGO.)

Comment: Do you mean that even if the LmCompatibilityLevel level on the client and the server machine is 2, it could still happen that NTLMv2 is used? I do not have access to the domain controller's registry keys to verify the value of LmCompatibilityLevel on it. I will have a look and confirm this. I have used HTTPAnalyzer to capture HTTP request which does not detail on the NTLM version being used. I will try Wireshark and follow up. Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: I checked the details on wireshark. I didn't find a way to confirm whether NTLMv1 is used or NTLMv2. On troubleshooting more I realized that the NTLM response in Type 3 message is not generated by commons httpclient 3.1 but it is generated by the JDK implementation of the NTLM protocol implementation. Not sure if this could be the cause of the issue. Another question posted here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916820/how-can-i-get-jcifs-to-play-nicely-with-apache-axis also mentions about it in the answer but there are not enough details. Let me know if you have any details on this. Thanks

Comment: NTLM authentication will certainly fail without that type 3 response.  You can look at the flags to see that the NEGOTIATE_NTLM2 flag is set (or not) in the response.  As for the other issue, I've not used the JCIFS code to generate NTLM responses.  But the specification for NTLM2 is available from Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc236621(v=PROT.13).aspx

Comment: Does this mean (not having NTLM response in Type3 message) that commons http client only supports LAN Manager authentication and it does NOT support NTLM authentication? If so then a LmCompatibilityLevel value of 4 or 5 would mean that commons http client NTLM authentication does not work which could be the case with the windows machine I mention. I do not have access rights to check the domain controller registry keys. Let me know if you have any thoughts on this. Thank you.

Comment: Commons httpclient definitely supports NTLM (the original NTLM, not NTLM2.)  Not having a Type 3 message would indicate that the sender delivered an NTLMv2 type 2 message and commons httpclient is not able to create a response to it.  You simply can't use stock httpclient 3 to authenticate using NTLM2, you can either upgrade to httpcomponents httpclient 4, you can use the Java builtin, you can use JCIFS to build NTLM messages for httpclient 3, or you can roll your own NTLM authenticator for httpclient 3 using the available MS specification (above).

Comment: The Type3 message is constructed by httpclient 3.1. It just does not have NTLM Response. It computes the LAN Manager Hash (LM hash) but does not compute the NTLM hash. This means that httpclient 3.1 does not completely support NTLM v1 and we could face a problem explained in my above comment right?

Comment: Unfortunately my assumption was wrong. The LmCompatibilityLevel value on the domain controller is 1 and that on the server is 2. Need to do some more investigations